# php how do i add my logged information when submitting stuff like echo and disabled textbox

Tags: php

ok this is my code
the part that makes it hard for me to record is the disable part
and i want my textbox to be disabled and have my "logged in account" information to be automatically inputted

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="text"> Customer Name</label>

    **<input type="text" value=" <?php  echo $row['userfirstName'];  echo '&nbsp;'; echo $row['userlastName'];  ?> " class="form-control" id="customername" name="customername" disabled>**

        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="text"> Mailing Address</label>
        **<input type="text" value=" <?php  echo $row['userAddress']; ?> " class="form-control" id="customeraddress" name="customeraddress" disabled>**


        </div>
```

[image: Photo]

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking but you probably want to use `readonly` instead of `disabled`

Comment: oops sorry
<input type="text" value=" <?php  echo $row['userfirstName'];  echo '&nbsp;'; echo $row['userlastName'];  ?> " class="form-control" id="customername" name="customername" disabled>**

what i want to happen is to successfully insert the echo part  and have the textbox more like.. disabled/uneditable 
but making it disabled is making my code not work and not register in the db... aight imma try the readonly part...

Comment: It worked!!!!!  darn thanksss :)!! where's the check button or thank button i got lost :o

Comment: I'll add an answer so you can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set a form field to disabled the values in it are not sent back to the server, if you want the field to uneditable but still posted use `readonly` instead of `disabled`